# Function name with a leading underscore

Tags: julia

In my codes, I am using function names with a leading underscore like `_foo()` for some purposes, but wondering whether this might have possible side effects, e.g., interference with functions exported from basic libraries. For example, I see error messages like

```
ERROR: LoadError: ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] _printf(::String, ::Expr, ::String, ::Tuple{Symbol,Expr,Symbol,Expr}) at ./printf.jl:1209
 ...
 [7] _start() at ./client.jl:432
```

Although I guess these are internal functions in libraries (not exported), is it safe to use such a leading underscore for user-defined functions (at least when using only the standard libraries)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically names starting with an underscore are used for internal functions or variables, but this is only a stylistic convention. It is safe to use them in your own code, except for the following rule:

*names consisting of only underscores like `_` or `__` are used as a black hole (you can write to them, but not read from them).*

Typically names with leading `_` are not exported. An exception in Base is `__precompile__` function.

Below I give a more general comment, but related to what you ask and from my experience it is worth to know it.

Function and variable names are defined in a module scope which means that if you create your own module you can have a name conflicting with the same name in the other module and it will not be a problem (no matter if you have a leading underscore in it or not). You just have to qualify the name then:

```
julia> module MyModule
       export sin
       sin(x) = "sin($x)"
       end
Main.MyModule

julia> using .MyModule

julia> sin(1)
WARNING: both MyModule and Base export "sin"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
ERROR: UndefVarError: sin not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0

julia> Base.sin(1)
0.8414709848078965

julia> MyModule.sin(1)
"sin(1)"
```

The only corner case that is usually tricky is that you are allowed to define your own function name in a module (in particular in `Main` module) only if that name was not *imported from some other module and referenced to*. Here is an example:

```
julia> sin(x) = "sin($x)"
sin (generic function with 1 method)

julia> sin(10)
"sin(10)"

julia> cos(10)
-0.8390715290764524

julia> cos(x) = "cos($x)"
ERROR: error in method definition: function Base.cos must be explicitly imported to be extended
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Here both `sin` and `cos` are imported from `Base`. You defined `sin` in module `Main` before using it so it was OK. However, you used `cos` from `Base` before trying to define it so it was an error.

Comment: Thanks very much for detailed explanations (and also the behavior of _ and __). And the last part seems very tricky, because the behavior changes depending on whether a function is "called (invoked) first" or "defined first" in the current scope. (I played with this also for functions in separate modules, and the behavior was essentially the same as the sin/cos example above.) Thanks very much :)

Comment: This behavior is needed if you want to allow a flow of development in Julia that most people expect. The corner case is only when e.g. you first call some function from a different module and then try to define a new function with the same name in the calling module (you can add a new method the called function by using `import` even if you called it earlier though). In practice it happens very rarely so it is not a big deal (but it might surprise you if you are not aware of this quirk).